# Serializing Guid to MongoDB as a BsonString and not BinData?

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization

I have a class that has the following property

```
[BsonId]
public Guid EventId { get; private set; }
```

I would like to serialize(and deserialize) the class that has this property to MongoDB with the use of the `ToBsonDocument` method. Though through the use of the default serializer the resulting BSON type for the `_id` field is

```
"_id" : BinDate(3, "wX9ZnP0ApEWF0d5aXLgiUA==")
```

I would like it to be stored as a `BsonString`. I plan to create a custom `SerializerBase<>` extension class in the future to properly deserialize the string back to a `Guid` I just have not gotten there yet.

I know that I could simply change my property to be a `String`

```
[BsonId]
public String EventId { get; private set; }
```

But I would like to keep it as a `Guid`. I think to solve my problem I need to make use of a serialization tag but I am not sure which one, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I somehow managed to find my answer right after I posted this question.

By making use of the tag `BsonRepresentation` I can specify the BSON data type that I would like MongoDB to use when serializing the data.

```
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
```